# Flutter navigation using BLoC: The context used to push routes from the Navigator must be a descendant of a Navigator widget

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc

I am using BLoC and I need to navigate from PageOne to PageTwo and be able to return with the back button, I do not know if this is the correct way to handle this problem.
I'm also getting an error when function *_navigateToPage2* is called.

> The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.

```dart
class SimpleBlocDelegate extends BlocDelegate {

  @override
  void onTransition(Transition transition) {
     print(transition);
  }

  @override
  void onError(Object error, StackTrace stacktrace) {
      print(error);
   }
}



void main() {
  BlocSupervisor().delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  runApp(MyApp(userRepository: UserRepository(GuriApi())));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserRepository userRepository;

  MyApp({Key key, @required this.userRepository}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  AuthenticationBloc _authenticationBloc;
  UserRepository get _userRepository => widget.userRepository;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _authenticationBloc = AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: _userRepository);
    _authenticationBloc.dispatch(AppStarted());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _authenticationBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
      bloc: _authenticationBloc,
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(
            fontFamily: 'Monserrat',
            primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
            accentColor: Colors.white),
        home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState>(
          bloc: _authenticationBloc,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AuthenticationState state) {
            if (state is AuthenticationUninitialized) {
              return SplashPage();
            }
            if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
              return Home(userRepository: _userRepository);
            }
            if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
              return LoginPage(userRepository: _userRepository);
            }
            if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
              return LoadingIndicator();
            }
            if (state is PageOneSelected) {
              return PageOne();
            }
            if (state is PageTwoSelected) {
              _navigateToPage2();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _navigateToPage2() {
    Navigator.of(context).push<bool>(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                PageTwo(userRepository: _userRepository)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think it is better to handle navigation by subscribing to the bloc state change in initState:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    bloc.state.listen((state) {
        if (state is PageOneSelected) {
            _navigateToPage2();
        } else if (state is PageTwoSelected) {
            _navigateToPage2();
        }
    });
}
```

Show some other widget in build method. Error occurs in your code because blocBuilder has to return Widget but in case of  PageTwoSelected state you return nothing.

Comment: You sir just saved my life. I've searched all over the internet for an answer. Thanks for making this community a better place

Answer (score 1):

it's necessary to do something like this in your widget:

```
     if (state is PageTwoSelected) {
         WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
            Navigator.push(context, 
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                PageTwo(userRepository: _userRepository))
            );
         });
     }
```

This is necessary because if the navigation happens while the widget is still being built (in a dirty state), Flutter will throw an exception.

By nesting it in the callback of addPostFrameCallback you are basically saying when the widget is done building, then execute the navigation code.

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-login-tutorial-with-flutter-bloc-ea606ef701ad), there is explanation in the comments.